# Returning Jsonify to a html page with css

Tags: json, flask

I am currently working on a FLASK app that handles user logins. The idea behind it is that when a user enters his login credentials, the form would send his information to an API that will determine if the login is successful or otherwise. The API will send a message to display if it was a success or not. The API and template pages work fine and I am able to return the message using jsonify but I would like to return the jsonify  data to a html page which has my css designs and extends my "base.html" Here's what I have so far:

My Login API

```
def index():
code, message = "ERROR", "Invalid Credentials"
loginid = str(request.form.get('id')) or ''
pw = str(request.form.get('pw')) or ''

if len(loginid) == 0 or len(pw) == 0:
    # Fields not filled
    message = "Please fill in all required fields"
    return jsonify({"code": code, "message": message})


if get_user(loginid, pw):
    # Authentication Sucessful
    code, message = "OK", "Authentication successful."
    regen_session()

    session['auth'] = True
    session['user'] = loginid
    return jsonify({"code": code, "message": message})

# User credentials error
return jsonify({"code": code, "message": message})
```

Could someone show me how I can return the jsonify object to a page that has my html and css ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I always use JSON dataType to communicate between client and server using javascript.

I provide working example here:

**HTML part and jquery ajax:**

```
    <input type="text" id="id_field">
    <input type="password" id="pass_field">
    <button type="button" onclick="sendData()">ok</button> 

    <script>
    function sendData (){
    var get_id = document.getElementById("id_field").value
    var get_pass = document.getElementById("pass_field").value

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{url_for('index')}}",
                data: JSON.stringify({id: get_id,pw: get_pass}),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    //handle response here      
                },
                error: function(data){
                   //handle errors here
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

**Flask PART:**

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST']) 
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginid = request.json.get('id')
        pw = request.json.get('pw')

        # do whatever with data then return jsonify data to ajax function

        return jsonify({"code": code, "message": message})
```